# Issue with Loading SVG Content into Fabric.js Using fabric.loadSVGFromString

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am encountering a problem with loading SVG content into Fabric.js using the fabric.loadSVGFromString method. Despite having a valid SVG string, the loaded objects array in the callback appears to be empty.

Code:

```
let state;

// Function to clear the canvas and store its state as an SVG string
function clearCanvas() {
  state = canvas.toSVG();
  if (canvas.getObjects().length > 0) {
    canvas.getObjects().forEach((item) => canvas.remove(item));
  } else {
    console.warn("There is nothing to clear");
  }
}

// Function to restore the canvas state from the stored SVG string
function restoreCanvas() {
  if (state) {
    fabric.loadSVGFromString(state, (objects, options, error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error loading SVG:", error);
      } else {
        // Here i supposed to get objects instead getting empty array
        console.log(objects);
        //canvas.clear();
        //canvas.add(...objects);
        //canvas.renderAll();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Additional Details:**

The clearCanvas function clears the canvas and stores its state as an SVG string (state).
The restoreCanvas function attempts to load objects back into the canvas using the fabric.loadSVGFromString method. The loaded objects are logged to the console, but the array appears to be empty.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

Checked that the state variable contains a valid SVG string before calling fabric.loadSVGFromString.
Ensured there are no errors logged in the console during the loading process.
Simplified the SVG content to a basic example for testing.

**Request for Assistance:**
Seeking guidance on why the objects array is empty despite having a valid SVG string. Any insights or suggestions for resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try stripping off the xml tag?: `var state= canvas.toSVG({suppressPreamble: true});`

Comment: Quite sure this happens because you have removed  all items before - so the item references to the original object still exist. A workaround would be to remove  all elements after returning the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it is returning empty array but i tried another way and it works instead of converting into SVG i simply converted into json and then in restore i just parsed and its working perfectly fine:

```
//Store
state = JSON.stringify(canvas.toObject());

//Parse
const obj = JSON.parse(state);
```